# ClassNotFoundException reports on Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android

I Have some crash reports in my Google Play Console that I can not explain or reproduce. It seems that it only happens to a very small number of users on multiple devices and Android versions.

The Android versions that have reported the crash are. Android 4.4, Android 5.1, Android 6.0.

I Only have a total of 10 reports on this issue but it does seem to happen every time I publish an update for my app. The app works fine on my devices and multiple emulators as well as for most of my users. I Have about 40.000 active installations, if it would affect a large number of users I would expect to see much more crash reports.

I've tried to look up other posts here on Stackoverflow and while there are some simular reports most of them would have a class name in the report specifying which reference to which class was causing the issue. In my case as you can see in the report the classname is empty.

The android:name attribute in my application tag in my manifest is set to the correct classname including the full package name. All other classes also seem to be set correctly in the manifest file.

Some stackoverflow post mention multidex settings. I'm not using that setting in my gradle file. I've done an inspection of my build apk file to see how many method counts there were and the result was way below the maximum, so I don't see any need to turn on the multidex option.

I'm a bit out of ideas what can be the cause of this issue, but if it's possible I would like to fix it. Even if it's only a small number of people affected by this, that is still some people that might have a bad experience with my app because of it.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4539)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1318)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5350)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java:0)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:993)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
```

Comment: Do you use minifyEnabled true? Since when have you got reports? You should immediately install crash system like Crashlytics. 10 GP reports are from users whish tapped "Reporn" button. In my project 10 meant 20% session crashes. Please, provide  additional information about your project.

Comment: @YuriyKot I Do use Proguard. After reading more post I found that it might help to add a keep class rule in the proguard file for the application class. I'm going to try that with my next update.

Comment: @user1103538 Hi, did you find any solution for this issue? I'm having exactly the same now :(

Comment: @kodlan I never found a real solution to this issue. I Also never had any user complain about it. I've only been able to reproduce the error one time in an emulator. Basically what happened was I updated the app in the emulator, there was a crash message about my app and that was it. It happened at the time the update was being installed. After that the app runned fine. I suspect this is the cause of my reports on Google play as well. Something goes wrong when the update is being installed causing the app to crash, then once the update is installed the app runs fine.

Comment: @user1103538 Thank you for the answer. Did you try enabling multidex for your app? Did it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer just in case someone is having the same issue as me.
I had the same exception reported in Google Play console and wasn't able to reproduce it on my device.

My app was using library project that had service and boot receiver that were mentioned in the app's manifest. But those were removed in the library. Build didn't fail and the app was working as expected from users point of view. But during update it was crashing with this exception and this is how it got to Play console.

So check you manifest for wrong services/receivers etc.